# Using linspace but including endpoints in Runge-Kutta method

Tags: matlab

I've been given a stepsize h that to be used in the implementation of a Runge-Kutta method for higher order ODEs. My problem comes when dividing up the interval from the starting time t_0 to the final time t_f. I thought of using `N = ceil((t_f-t_i)/h)`, and then using

```
t = linspace(t_0, t_f, N)
```

But I want to keep the points used by the Runge-Kutta algorithm spaced by h for most of the process, is there a way to include the endpoint t_f while keeping the stepsize at `h` for the first n-1 steps? I tried using

```
t = t_0:h:t_f
```

But this does not always include the endpoint t_f.

Comment: Which could lead to a duplex at the end

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want use the largest N such that your range is t_0, t_0 + h, t_0 + 2*h, ..., t_0 + h*(N-2), t_f, you would use `t = [t_0 : h : t_f-eps t_f]`, where `eps` is a MATLAB function that gives the smallest distance between two floating point numbers.

Be aware that this means your last two points can be very close together. In general, if you write `t = [t_0 : h : t_f-a t_f]` with a < h, then the distance between the final two points will be in the interval [a, h+a).